# My car isn't moving with the heuristics only setting (unity mlagents)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 3d

This is the first time I use a car with the mlagents package, and I ran into a problem with getting the car to move mainly because the car's motion is different than that of a normal object. What could I be doing wrong? I'm using wheel colliders and the car is 4 wheel drive.

The code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using Unity.MLAgents;
using Unity.MLAgents.Actuators;
using Unity.MLAgents.Sensors;

public class MLCar : Agent
{
    [SerializeField] private Transform targetTransform;
    [SerializeField] private Material winMaterial;
    [SerializeField] private Material loseMaterial;
    [SerializeField] private MeshRenderer floorMeshRenderer;
    public override void OnEpisodeBegin()
    {
        transform.localPosition = new Vector3(UnityEngine.Random.Range(-44, -10), UnityEngine.Random.Range(1f, 1f), UnityEngine.Random.Range(-18f, 24f));
        targetTransform.localPosition = new Vector3(UnityEngine.Random.Range(+1.5f, +4.7f), UnityEngine.Random.Range(0.717f, 0.717f), UnityEngine.Random.Range(-1.8f, 1.8f));
    }

    public override void CollectObservations(VectorSensor sensor)
    {
        sensor.AddObservation(transform.localPosition);
        sensor.AddObservation(targetTransform.localPosition);
    }
    private float horizontalInput, verticalInput;
    private float currentSteerAngle, currentbreakForce;
    private bool isBreaking;
    // Settings
    [SerializeField] private float motorForce, breakForce, maxSteerAngle;

    // Wheel Colliders
    [SerializeField] private WheelCollider frontLeftWheelCollider, frontRightWheelCollider;
    [SerializeField] private WheelCollider rearLeftWheelCollider, rearRightWheelCollider;

    // Wheels
    [SerializeField] private Transform frontLeftWheelTransform, frontRightWheelTransform;
    [SerializeField] private Transform rearLeftWheelTransform, rearRightWheelTransform;

    private void Update()
    {
        HandleMotor();
        HandleSteering();
        UpdateWheels();
    }
    public override void OnActionReceived(ActionBuffers actions)
    {
        float horizontalInput = actions.ContinuousActions[0];
        float verticalInput = actions.ContinuousActions[1];        
    }

    public override void Heuristic(in ActionBuffers actionsOut)
    {
        ActionSegment<float> continousActions = actionsOut.ContinuousActions;
        // Steering Input
        continousActions[0] = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");

        // Acceleration Input
        continousActions[1] = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
        Debug.Log("Yes");
        HandleMotor();
        HandleSteering();
        UpdateWheels();
        // Breaking Input
        isBreaking = Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space);
    }

    private void HandleMotor()
    {
        frontLeftWheelCollider.motorTorque = verticalInput * motorForce;
        frontRightWheelCollider.motorTorque = verticalInput * motorForce;
        currentbreakForce = isBreaking ? breakForce : 0f;
        ApplyBreaking();
    }

    private void ApplyBreaking()
    {
        frontRightWheelCollider.brakeTorque = currentbreakForce;
        frontLeftWheelCollider.brakeTorque = currentbreakForce;
        rearLeftWheelCollider.brakeTorque = currentbreakForce;
        rearRightWheelCollider.brakeTorque = currentbreakForce;
    }

    private void HandleSteering()
    {
        currentSteerAngle = maxSteerAngle * horizontalInput;
        frontLeftWheelCollider.steerAngle = currentSteerAngle;
        frontRightWheelCollider.steerAngle = currentSteerAngle;
    }

    private void UpdateWheels()
    {
        UpdateSingleWheel(frontLeftWheelCollider, frontLeftWheelTransform);
        UpdateSingleWheel(frontRightWheelCollider, frontRightWheelTransform);
        UpdateSingleWheel(rearRightWheelCollider, rearRightWheelTransform);
        UpdateSingleWheel(rearLeftWheelCollider, rearLeftWheelTransform);
    }

    private void UpdateSingleWheel(WheelCollider wheelCollider, Transform wheelTransform)
    {
        Vector3 pos;
        Quaternion rot;
        wheelCollider.GetWorldPose(out pos, out rot);
        wheelTransform.rotation = rot;
        wheelTransform.position = pos;
    }
    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.tag == "Finish")
        {
            SetReward(+1f);
            floorMeshRenderer.material = winMaterial;
            EndEpisode();
        }

        if (other.tag == "Respawn")
        {
            SetReward(-2f);
            floorMeshRenderer.material = loseMaterial;
            EndEpisode();
        }
    }
}
```

I tried changing up the code, but nothing seems to work..